# 3 and 4 degree curves in three.js

Tags: three.js, bezier

I am trying to reproduce the degree-3 or degree-4 3D curves typically found in parametric cad programs like Rhino or Autocad, which take any number of 3D points to create long curves. I've found that three.js has Cubic (degree-3) and Quadratic (degree-4) Bezier curves available but they take exactly three and 4 vectors, respectively. I'd like to create curves with 10 or more inputs, not just 3 or 4. I've also found that three.js has 'Path' which allows building a 2D curve of mixed degree segments using the .bezierCurveTo() or .quadraticCurveTo() methods.

So my question:
Is there currently a way to construct long chains of CubicBezierCurve3 curves that join smoothly? Ideally with a constructor that takes a simple array of vertices?

If I need to implement this myself, where is the best place to start? I'm thinking the .quadraticCurveTo() method could be extended to use a z component and added to SplineCurve3? I'm not 100% clear on how the array of curves works in the 'Path' object.

```
THREE.Path.prototype.quadraticCurveTo = function( aCPx, aCPy, aX, aY ) {

var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );

var lastargs = this.actions[ this.actions.length - 1 ].args;

var x0 = lastargs[ lastargs.length - 2 ];
var y0 = lastargs[ lastargs.length - 1 ];

var curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve( new THREE.Vector2( x0, y0 ),
                                            new THREE.Vector2( aCPx, aCPy ),
                                            new THREE.Vector2( aX, aY ) );
this.curves.push( curve );

this.actions.push( { action: THREE.PathActions.QUADRATIC_CURVE_TO, args: args } );
```

};

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with using a high degree Bezier curve, then you can implement it using De Casteljau algorithm. The link in karatedog's answer provides a good source for this algorithm. If you want to stick with degree 3 polynomial curve with many control points, B-spline curve will be a good choice. B-spline curve can be implemented using Cox de Boor algorithm. You can find plenty of reference on the internet. B-spline curve definition requires degree, control points and knot vector. If you want your function to simply take an array of 3d points, you can set degree = 3 and internally define the knot vector as

[0, 0, 0, 0, 1/(N-3), 2/(N-3),....., 1, 1, 1, 1].

where N = number of control points.

For example,

N=4, knot vector=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
N=5, knot vector=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
N=6, knot vector=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 1, 1, 1].

For the N=4 case, the B-spline curve is essentially the same as a cubic Bezier curve.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to karatedog and fang for your in-depth answers. In searching for more information about B-spline curve, I stumbled upon this extra library for [Three.js NURBS](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_nurbs.html) which is exactly what I needed. Upon closer inspection of the THREE.NURBSCurve() constructor in this library, it's implemented exactly as fang described: with arrays of both control points and knots. Knots are defined similarly to the method described above. I'm Marking Fang's answer as correct but I wanted to add this link to the pre-existing library as well, so any n00bs like myself could use it :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your finding about Three.js NURBS. I am not aware of its existence either. Therefore, this deserves a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement your own calculation algorithm, it is fairly easy, the learning process is short and worth the time invested. Check this page: http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

It describes a method (language agnostic) that you can calculate Beziér curves with any number of control points, although the a calculation that is specific to a certain number of control points (like cubic or quadratic) can be highly optimized.

Comment: Well, a Bezier curve defined by N control points is of degree (N-1). So, it will in general not cubic (which is what the OP asked for). For a piecewise cubic degree curve defined by arbitrary number of control points, you should be looking at cubic B-spline curve.

Comment: I'm sure the OP wants to create a Beziér curve with 10 (or whatever number) control points and not a cubic curve with an arbitrary number of control points. Anyway, using de Casteljau method the algorithm is the same for cubic, quartic or degree 10 curve, that is why I suggested he should have a look at it.